# Next function not called if authentication fail passport

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am using Passport.js with Express

This is the strategy:

```
passport.use(
  new Strategy(async function(username, password, done) {
    try {
      var user = await db.findOne("users", { username: username });
      if (!user) {
        console.log(`Incorrect username`.red);
        return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect username" });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return done(error);
    }

    if (username !== user.username) {
      return done(null, false, { message: "Icorrect user!" });
    }
    if (password !== user.password) {
      // console.log("Incorrect Password");
      return done(null, false, { message: "Icorrect password!" });
    }
    return done(null, user, { message: "user lorem ipsum" });
  })
);
```

Upon login post request authentication is performed:

```
app.post(
    "/Login",
    // checkCred,
    passport.authenticate("local", {
      failureFlash: true,
      successFlash: true
    }),
    // The following function is only invoked if authentication succeeded
    (req, res) => {
      console.log(`Called`.red);
      console.log(`CAAALEEEEE`.green);

      res.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          status: "ok",
          message: "OK",
          redirect: "/User",
          user: req.user ? req.user : "user not found in request"
        })
      );
      // res.redirect("/User");
    }
  );
```

If the authentication didn't pass, the second `(req, res) => {` function is never called. 
How to make the passport to call next() function so I can return response to the user?

Answer (score 0):

By default, `passport.authenticate()` returns 401 Unauthorized for unsuccessful login or continues to next middleware with `req.user` filled. You can override the default behavior in a couple of ways:

1. with `successRedirect` or `failureRedirect` options to `authenticate()`
2. provide a custom callback to `authenticate()` where you make any redirects you'd like and manually call `req.logIn()`

In your case, I'd remove the (req, next) handler completely and use `successRedirect` and `failureRedirect` like this

```
app.post("/Login", passport.authenticate("local", {
  successRedirect: "/User",
  failureRedirect: "/Login",
  failureFlash: true,
  successFlash: true,
}));
```

Remember to add needed packages to show the flash messages.

Comment: I would like to return a custom message to the user, that informs him about login failure.

Comment: @Hairi `failureFlash: true` displays default message for the authentication strategy. You can pass custom message by changing the boolean to a string like this `failureFlash: "Invalid username or password"`. Remember to render the flash messages when you render your pages.